# Object Oriented Model on top of LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, oop, persistence

I'm playing a bit with LINQ to SQL and overall it's a much better option than what Microsoft had before (DataSet), but it seems that object-oriented capabilities are still limited. Since we currently use a custom persistence framework that created a OO model on top of DataSet, I'm looking to port the framework to a new version building a OO Model on top of LINQ to SQL.

1. First is there any other similar initiative?
2. Second do you think it's a good idea to go this way?

Answer (score 1):

For # 1, you may be looking for the newer Linq to Entity. Here's one place to start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Rob Conery is developing a new type of repository pattern in his [store front series](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/). AFAIK, it uses OO object over LINQ to SQL. It contains a lot of talk about MVC and TDD but it's still worth a watch to see what he's doing with LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve made of test of this in my project project.
Take a look at:[openticket.codeplex.com](http://openticket.codeplex.com)